# Does ASW Code build report supports .Net code coverage tools?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-codebuild

I am working on a Dot Net Core project and I want to add a code coverage report to AWS Code Build. I see from the following page there are no supported tools related to Dot Net https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/code-coverage-report.html. It would be great if anyone guides me on how to add a code coverage report for Dot Net application in AWS Code Deploy.

Comment: are you looking for something like [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/i7bpua/codebuild_test_coverage_with_net_core/) ?

Comment: Thanks @amitd. that's exactly what I was looking for.